# Import csv data into google sheets using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

I would like to import a csv file into Google Sheets using Apps Script. I would like to add the csv file to be read to the existing tab "csv_data" after the last line. Can someone help me? I am a starting apps script user. Thank you in advance for your help! GJM

Comment: You need to give it a try writing something in your Apps Script. If it partially works or does not work, you can share it under your question. You will get help if you tag your question and post the script along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a useful method, called [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)

If your csv file is located on your Google drive, you can import and append it e.g. by attaching to your spreadsheet a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) with the following content:

```
function appendCSV() {  
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("PASTE HERE THE NAME OF YOUR CSV FILE INCLUDING EXTENSION").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(),'SPECIFY HERE THE DELIMITER (OPTIONAL)');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);  
}
```