# How to get the excel data from a url into google sheets using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Follow up question to this question - [How to fix invalid url error using UrlfetchApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330053/how-to-fix-invalid-url-error-using-urlfetchapp/63332264#63332264)

This is the url to download the excel data from :
`https://corvo-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/TRESAH/2020-08-16/45d32ff8-bccd-4c16-8916-6c19c28f2f3c%402020-08-16%2017%3A30%3A00.0/Sponsored%20Products%20Search%20term%20report%20-%20Scotch%20Brite.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200816T174421Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604799&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAY2R3XYZC46Q4PK5E%2F20200816%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=726ca9b98cd766966b756bc708b780377ff62e5bbfec8c09b97294bfb0cd63f7`

This is a report that comes in on a schedule and I need to take this data and put it in a google sheet. It's a large report so I need to clear all existing data on the sheet and replace it with the new data. I've been struggling with this and could use some help.

This is the code I have right now:

```
// Globals
const DataFolderId = 'XXXXX'
const label = 'YYYYY'

/*
* Download the excel file and put it in a google sheet
*
* @return : Hopefully, it adds the data to the google sheet
*/
function excelToSheets() {    
  
  // Get the link to the excel file
  const url = getDownloadLink(label) 
  const excelFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob()
  const filename = 'Report: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  
  // Download the file to google drive
  const fileInfo = {
  title: filename,
  mimeType: "MICROSOFT_EXCEL",
  "parents": [{'id': DataFolderId}],
}  

// Currently, this adds a zip file to google drive, instead of an excel/google sheet file
const file = Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo, excelFile, {convert: true})  

// Assign the id of the downloaded file to a variable
const id = file.id

// Put data in a spreadsheet - this does not work
spreadsheet(id)

}


/*
* Helper function to put data in the google sheet
*/
function spreadsheet (id) {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  const destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data')
  destination.clearContents()
  source.copyTo(destination)  
}


/*
* Get the download link from the gmail label
*
* @return : The link from the most recent email
*/
function getDownloadLink (label) {
  
  const lookupLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label)
  const thread = lookupLabel.getThreads()[0]  
  const message = thread.getMessages()[0]  
  const data = message.getPlainBody()
  const regExp = new RegExp('[\n\r].*Download:\\s*([^\n\r]*)')
  const link = regExp.exec(data)[1].trim()
  
  return link 
}
```

Currently, the `excelToSheets()` function takes the excel file from the link and adds a zip file in google drive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - I've just been trying to follow a bunch of tutorials on the topic online.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch a blob from a download link it might not contain the correct mimeType information

Workaround

**Perform the request in two steps**

1. step save the file as Excel on your Drive
2. Convert the Excel file to Google Sheets

**Sample**

```js
function excelToSheets() {    
  
  const url = getDownloadLink(label); 
  const excelFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  const filename = 'Report: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  const fileInfo = {
    title: filename,
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    parents: [{id: DataFolderId}],
  }  
  
  const file = Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo, excelFile)  
  const id = file.id;
  const excelFile2 = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
  const fileInfo2 = {
    title: filename,
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id: DataFolderId}],
  }  
  const file2 = Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo2, excelFile2); 
  const id2 = file2.id;
  spreadsheet(id2)
  
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! As a follow up question, say I get a csv file instead of an excel file by the same method - would this work? Or would I need to use some other mimeType to read that csv file?

Comment: csv is easier, you can use [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282088/11599789).